# Hide control on word doc save event

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to hide a  control on document save i,e file->save.But no luck.can any body help

Comment: instead of help down vte .great.

Comment: @olle I tried placing code in close venet and it works.Thanks osaka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your code in document close event. It should probably work.